# How to get the target class of a groovy mixin?

Tags: grails, groovy, enums, internationalization, mixins

I'm trying to do the following in Grails:

```
class I18nEnum implements MessageSourceResolvable {
    public Object[] getArguments() { [] as Object[] }
    public String[] getCodes() { [ this.class.canonicalName+'.'+name() ] }
    public String getDefaultMessage() { "?-" + name() }
}
```

and then use this class like this:

```
class MyDomainClass {
    @Mixin(I18nEnum)
    public static enum MaritalStatus {
        SINGLE, MARRIED
    }
    MaritalStatus maritalStatus
}
```

Then MyDomainClass is used with scaffolding to generate an HTML select field, and to have the options translatable in messages.properties like this:

```
my.package.MyDomainClass.MaritalStatus.SINGLE  = Single
my.package.MyDomainClass.MaritalStatus.MARRIED = Married
```

But I cannot find a way to get the name of the **target class** (*my.package.MyDomainClass.MaritalStatus*), and instead I get the name of the **mixin class** (*my.package.I18nEnum@1dd658e9*)

**How can I get the target class of a groovy mixin?**

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
    public String[] getCodes() { [ this.targetClass.canonicalName+'.'+name() ] }
```

Or like this?

```
    public String[] getCodes() { [ this.mixinTargetClass.canonicalName+'.'+name() ] }
```

---

***Note:*** For the moment the only way that I made this *enum internationalization feature* to work was by just copy-pasting this for every enum class defined in the application:

```
public static enum MaritalStatus implements MessageSourceResolvable {
    SINGLE, MARRIED
    public Object[] getArguments() { [] as Object[] }
    public String[] getCodes() { [ this.class.canonicalName+'.'+name() ] }
    public String getDefaultMessage() { name() }
}
MaritalStatus maritalStatus
```

But I would like to **not repeat** the same code for every enum, but instead just **mixin** the required methods implementing *MessageSourceResolvable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixins do not work with enums. May be it will be useful for you:

```
class Mix {
    def enumClazz
    Mix(def clz) { enumClazz = clz }
    def getCode() { println "---> ${enumClazz.name()}"}
}


enum MaritalStatus {
    SINGLE, MARRIED    

    @Delegate Mix mixClz = new Mix(this)
}

MaritalStatus.MARRIED.code
```